# $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] gives me just hosting IP, not user's IP. Why?

Tags: php

Recently I've needed to change my counter code in my blog site. That is why some attackers manipulate counter numbers of my articles, using a program or anything else.

They can increment the counter to 4000 in a day. So I've changed the counter algorithm. Now I'm using a counter based on IP address. But I have a question about this. I know that `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` gives us *the IP address from which the user is viewing the current page*.

I taked this explanation from:  http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php. But this command didn't give me users' IP addresses. It always gave me just `hosting IP address`. Why?

Could anyone explain this situation, please? Fortunately, I've found a code snippet from the github, and I can use this new counter. (https://gist.github.com/cballou/2201933)

Why just the `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` doesn't work?

Comment: If you're really using `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']`, it could be that the requests really are originating from that server. That could indicate that you've been hacked.

Comment: I don't agree you. Because, when I used just $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], I tell my brother in different city to enter my web site. Then he saw just hosting IP address in the screen. ( I made IP address visible in the web page. ) Also, I saw hosting IP address in my database at that time. So you wrong.

Comment: There's no need to be rude. The request *is* coming from the server somehow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because some other piece of software on the server is initiating the request. This can be caused by e.g. reverse proxies or load balancers, or it may be a result of being hacked. One of the 'HTTP_*' elements of the same array should give you the real address if the bounced request is legitimate, otherwise it's time to back up all your data, wipe the server, and start over.

Comment: But, when I used this code snippet in  https://gist.github.com/cballou/2201933, my problem was solved.

Comment: That is to say my level of reading about your sentences is not good. I understand what you mean nearly, but the command which I mention before is a standard in PHP Manual. How can such code be affected by these effects? It's a standard. I don't understand that.

Comment: Because it's not actually a PHP standard. In fact, it has very little to do with PHP. It is a part of TCP/IP and HTTP. And both of those can be played with.